# MySQLのユーザー作成

Tags: mysql

MySQLにおいてユーザーを作成するには、以下の方法以外にありますか？

```
CREATE USER user
IDENTIFIED {BY password |
            EXTERNALLY |
            GLOBALLY AS 'external_name'}
[DEFAULT TABLESPACE tablespace]
[TEMPORARY TABLESPACE {tablespace | tablespace_group_name}]
[QUOTA {integer [K | M] | UNLIMITED} ON tablespace]
[PROFILE profile]
[PASSWORD EXPIRE]
[ACCOUNT {LOCK | UNLOCK}];
```

ユーザーを追加したい ということ と

どこを埋めればいいか ということ です

ほかの方法 は あって 画期的 であれば そちらをつかいたい という意図です

Comment: SQLとMySQLは言葉は似ていますが、まったく違うものです。タグはこちらで変更しておきました。今後ご注意ください。

Comment: わかりました 、

Comment: 「本当にやりたいことと聞きたいことがずれている」という[XY 問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701/19110)になっていそうな気がします。`CREATE USER` 以外の方法を知って何をなさりたいのかも [edit] から追記いただけませんでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ほかの方法はありません。`CREATE USER` 文を利用してください。

ユーザを作る際に様々なオプションが設定できますが、最もシンプルな設定であれば
ユーザ名(username)とパスワード(pass1234)とアクセス可能なホスト名(localhost)を記述する例は以下のようになります。

```
CREATE USER `username`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED BY 'pass1234';
```

きちんと[公式のドキュメント](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/create-user.html)にも紹介されています。

ドキュメントの最初にはすべてのオプションを網羅したSQLコマンドが出てくるのでびっくりするかもしれないですが、きちんとドキュメントを読み込めば使い方は理解できると思います。

参考URL
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/create-user.html
https://www.dbonline.jp/mysql/user/index1.html

Comment: ありがとうございます

Comment: また アカウントは複数可能でしょうか？ 複数アカウントをもたないと多ドメインでの使用で不都合がでるとおもうのですが

Comment: 新しい質問は新しく質問を。。と思いましたが、その程度であればご自身の環境で試してみてはいかがでしょう

Comment: アカウントとユーザーは別ですか？ そうですね 接続するサーバーがちがう（あるいはおなじ）だけですね

Answer (score 0):

MySQL の以前のバージョンでは、存在しないユーザーに対して GRANT で権限をつけるとユーザーが作成されました。最近のバージョンではエラーになるのでちゃんと CREATE USER を使用した方がいいです。

CREATE USER で作成したユーザーは mysql データベースの user テーブルに登録されます。
つまり user テーブルにユーザーデータを INSERT して FLUSH PRIVILEGES することでも CREATE USER と同じことは可能です。しかし user テーブルの構造はバージョン毎に異なりますし、CREATE USER の方が楽なので、通常はこの方法を使用することはないと思います。

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/adding-users.html